# Restrict access for different users in nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, nginx-location

My requirement is I have two different users type one is admin users and another is normal users . Admin users can access all URL and normal users are only able to access one URL when they try to access others URL they getting access denied .

Currently I able to set admin users rules , where admin users details are mentioned in .htpasswd and it's works fine . Below is configuration file .

> ```
>     server {
>     listen 8880;
>
>     server_name test.com;
>
>     auth_basic "Restricted Access";
>     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;
>
>     location / {
>         proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
>         proxy_http_version 1.1;
>         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
>         proxy_set_header Host $host;
>         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
>     }
> }
> ```

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`auth_basic off;`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic) to permit access to specific `location` blocks.

However, the `location` block must be complete (and can inherit some of the [proxy module configuration statements](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) from the surrounding block).

You may need to use a [regular expression `location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to match multiple URIs, as the permitted URI may specify other resource files.

For example:

```
auth_basic "Restricted Access";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
}

location ~ ^/(allowed/uri.html|some.js|some.css)$ {
    auth_basic off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
}
```

Comment: If I create to users file like httpasswd.users and another is httpasswd.admin then is it possible that httpasswd.admin users can access all url but httpasswd.users can access only test.com/dashboard

Comment: No, the two files would have a non-overlapping scope, But you could make sure that every entry in the `httpasswd.admin` file is also in the `httpasswd.users` file.